# Explain matplotlib contourf function

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to plot a decision region (based on the output of a logistic regression) with matplotlib contourf funtion. The code I am using:

```
subplot.contourf(x2, y2, P, cmap=cmap_light, alpha = 0.8)
```

where x2 and y2 are two 2D matrices generated via numpy meshgrids. P is computed using

```
P = clf.predict(numpy.c_[x2.ravel(), y2.ravel()])
P = P.reshape(x2.shape)
```

Each element of P is a boolean value based on the output of the logistic regresssion. The rendered plot looks like this
[image]

**My question is how does the contourf function know where to draw the contour based on a 2D matrix of boolean values?** (x2, y2 are just numpy meshgrids) I looked up the docs several times but could not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to illustrate what's happening, here is an example using the 2 first features (sepal length and width) of the iris dataset.

First, the regression is calculated from the given data (dots with black outline). Then, for each point of a grid covering the data, a prediction is calculated (small dots in a grid).  Note that the given and predicted values are just the numbers 0, 1 and 2. (In the question, only 0 and 1 are used.)

The last step is using these grid points as input to search contours of regions with an equal predicted value. So, a [contour line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line) is drawn between the grid points that have value 0 and the ones with value 1. And another between values 1 and 2. A `contourf` fills the area between the lines with a uniform color.

As the grid points and their prediction aren't visualized in the question's plot, the sudden contours are harder to understand.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X = X[:, :2]
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X, y)

x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(X[:, 0].min()-.5, X[:, 0].max()+.5, 20),
                     np.linspace(X[:, 1].min()-.5, X[:, 1].max()+.5, 20) )
pred = clf.predict(np.c_[x2.ravel(), y2.ravel()])

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Set1', 3)
plt.scatter(x2.ravel(), y2.ravel(), c=pred, s=10, cmap=cmap, label='Prediction on grid')
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=50, cmap=cmap, ec='black', label='Given values')
plt.contourf(x2, y2, pred.reshape(x2.shape), cmap=cmap, alpha=0.4, levels=2, zorder=0)
plt.legend(ncol=2, loc="lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,1.01))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: About `pred.reshape(x2.shape)`:

- `x2` and `y2` are arrays giving the x and y coordinate of each grid point. `x2` and `y2` are organized as 2D arrays similar to the grid they represent (20x020 in the example).
- However, the function `clf.predict` needs its input arrays to be 1d.  To that end, `.ravel()` is used: it just makes one long 1d array out of the 2d array. In the example, `ravel` converts the 20x20 arrays to 1d arrays of 400.
- The result of `pred = clf.predict` is a corresponding 1d array (400 elements).
- `pred.reshape(x2.shape)` converts `pred` to the same 2d format as `x2` and `y2` (again 20x20).
- Note that `scatter` wants its parameters in 1d format, it only looks at each point individually. `contourf` on the other hand wants its parameters in 2d format, as it needs to know how the grid is organized.

Comment: It's the pred.reshape(x2.shape) parameter that contains info about which grid point have what value (0, 1 or 2). This is what I was initially confused with.

Comment: I updated the answer with the motivation for `reshape(x2.shape)` and `x2.ravel()`.