# Plotting a graph with separating classes with color gradient

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data containing 3 columns or features namely X, Y, class - which looks like this

```
  X     Y   Colour
  0     0   Blue
  0     0.5 Blue
  0     1   Blue
  0.2   1   Blue
  0.4   2   Red
  0.4   2.5 Red
  .     
  .
  .
```

I plotted a scatter plot with X and Y parameter and third parameter as class which is shared below
[image]

But I want to separate classes via decision boundary and want something like this which I manually created using paint.
[image]

Kindly help I am trying using python matplotlib and Logistic Regression to create a separating boundary.

Comment: One option is to make the color column numeric and call `plt.contourf()` or `plt.tricontourf()`. See. e.g. [Explain matplotlib contourf function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63234019/explain-matplotlib-contourf-function)